# extracting data from raster file for specific coordinate and merge in R

Tags: r, loops, raster

I have gridded data files ( each file consist of monthly rainfall and is label pYYYYMM) https://www.dropbox.com/sh/63z166tjxyu12s5/AAAs3Ccn1zdVoBYMj8Y1o303a?dl=0

```
library(raster)
files= list.files( ,pattern='*.grd',full.names=TRUE)
df = NULL
for(i in seq_along(files)) {
r2 <- raster(files[i])
# setting the missing values to NA
r2[r2 >= 170141000918782798866653488190622531584.00] <- NA_real_
# Setting the projection
crs(r2) <- "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +datum=WGS84"
plot(r2)
#Doing this, got me the value for a given point but you will have to manual edit:
d1<- getValuesBlock(r2, row=42, nrows=1, col=26, ncols=1)
# Combine data to get one dataframe 
rbind(df,d1)->df
# then write to a csv file
}
```

The loop above works for me to an extent but it means that I have to manually change each point and then I will also have manually input the date.

I am kindly asking for some guidance on how I can modify my code to the data for the latitude and and longitude of my interest which is in this file 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3p4u4pyxkyo2q15/latandlong.csv?dl=0

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/148147/115

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would normally do this, assuming that all your grid files line up

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
files <- list.files(pattern='.grd$', full.names=TRUE)
s <- stack(files)
# points <- ...

# if your points are lonlat
points <- SpatialPoints(points[, c('longitude', 'latitude')], 
          proj4string=CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84'))
# and your raster data are not they need to be matched
pts <- spTransform(points, CRS("+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +datum=WGS84")

df <- extract(s, points)
write.csv(df, 'file.csv')
```

Comment: thanks for a response, I noticed you comment points and I read my csv with lat and long with this code points <- read.csv("latandlong.csv"). . But after running your codes. and open my file all I got was a while that consist of NAs ..i am not sure how to fix.. this my first time with raster data

Comment: My guess it that your coordinates are not in the right order. Use "lon - lat" and not "lat - lon". Plot them to check.

Comment: i tried that but same results.. I believe I need to set my missing values withing your codes ..but I am not certain how to get that done for stack ..I did it for one file in my codes above

Comment: You need to simplify your problem (single layer) and show more information, e.g. ` head(points)` and `show(s)` . Are you dealing with data in different coordinate reference systems? It seems so, and I have updated the answer to deal with that.

Comment: The principle you provided worked to an extent but  my points file had x and x values rather than actual coordinates.  Using the extract function will extract values  but but then i am not certain which values   correspond to which x and y. Do I need to ask a separate follow up question..( as i am really struggling with this raster dataset)

Comment: I would start by improving the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in two different coordinate systems or the .grd files are bad. I had a look at your actual data and my guess is that your data is from Canada, the lat and longs are in wgs-1984 and I'm unsure what is going on with your .grd files. There lower left hand corner starts at 0,0. If you extract correctly you will have all NA values because the data do not overlap. This is a data issue and not an R question.

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
#get extent of grid file
dat.dir<-'filelocations'
a<-raster(paste0(dat.dir,'/p201307.grd')
extent(a)
#class       : Extent 
#xmin        : -0.5 
#xmax        : 124.5 
#ymin        : -0.5 
#ymax        : 94.5 
#get locs
locs<-read.csv(paste0(dat.dir,'/latandlong.csv'))
head(locs)
#longitude latitude
# 1 -116.8736  60.0334
```

Comment: Dear Daisy, thank for your response  i got the data from this site ftp://ccrp.tor.ec.gc.ca/pub/EC_data/CANGRD/.  what i am trying to do extract data for each territories of canada and so that i can get a time series for each lat and longitude within the dataset.  I edit my question as robert suggested to see if i can be  clearer as it my first time with this type of data

Comment: If you read the description file, you will see that your gridded data is: 
"The CANGRD grid is in polar stereographic projection with a 50 km spatial resolution. The grid is a 125 (columns) by 95 (rows) matrix, where the SW corner (0,0) is at 40.0451°N latitude and 129.8530°W longitude. The projection is true at 60.0°N and centered on 110.0°W. The file ‘CANGRD_points_LL.txt’ lists the latitudes and longitudes for each grid point." You can create a raster from the txt file, extract the grid cells for your points, and use those grid  cells to extract a time series.